# Need Explanation java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-webflow

This is not a question. I am trying to find reason for following behavior.

I am developing simple web application involving technologies like Spring, Hibernate and Struts2.

I use Maven 3 as the build tool. When I am starting to run the project using eclipse Juno release, I'm getting following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

But in the `pom.xml` I have added the dependency for spring web framework and when I list the jars in eclipse, I can see this Context loader file is there.

But when I add the following plugin configuration to `pom.xml` , this exception is not thrown:

```
<plugin>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I just want to find a reason for this behavior. Thanks in advance for any clue.

I have integrated following maven plugins in to maven.

[image]

Comment: This post is the best advertisement for not using Maven or Spring I've ever seen.

Comment: I can't speak for Spring, but I agree with the "no Maven" part.  Why, Kltis?  Because it's a simple CLASSPATH problem, but you've got so much machinery between you and your understanding of how Java works that you can't figure it out.  Make this work without Eclipse or Maven before you use them.

Comment: @duffymo -- yeah, that's what I'm saying. As far as Spring goes, he's missing a class named `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`, but there's no way in creation he's explicitly used this class, or probably even knows what it is -- nor should he, on either count. Yet there it is: if you're using Eclipse, Maven and Spring, you're not figuring out how to write a simple web application: you're trying to figure out how to get Eclipse to tell Maven to load some class you don't even need.

Comment: I disagree, EFH.  He *does* need it.  It's in his web.xml; it's used to load the application context XML.  It's part of the Spring web module.  It should be in the WEB-INF/lib in the Spring JARs.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill , i agree with you with the saying that " you are trying to figure out how to get Eclipse to tell maven to load some classes you don't even need". But , problem is why it is only saying this class is missing, i have added several other dependencies, but for those , it does not throw an exception

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill its the best advertisement I have seen for not using eclipse

Answer (score 1):

add the maven dependencies to your deployment assembly